# How do I upgrade from CDI1.0 to CDI 1.1

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

For Java EE project I use JBoss AS7.1 and Eclipse IDE. In Eclipse I can see the current version of CDI under: **Project -> Properties -> ProjectFacets -> CDI**

[image]

How do I change the version to CDI 1.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared to upgrade your application server, then make the switch to WildFly 8 or higher (WildFly is the new name of JBoss AS). CDI 1.1 is part of the Java EE 7 spec, which is implemented in WildFly 8.*, GlassFish 4.*, et al. If you are not able to upgrade your application server, you might be able to drop a JAR of an implementation of CDI 1.1 into your build, but it would probably be better to upgrade to EE 7 if you can.